# No hreflang return tag detected by Google

Tags: html, seo, google-search, canonical-link, hreflang

I have some indexing errors on Google Search Console saying that many pages of my site have an alternate version in another language but they miss the "return tag" , which i think is the pointer back to the "canonical" version in English.

For example this page is the canonical one in English http://www.thebitles.com/ which points to the spanish version through this meta tag

```
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="/es/" />
```

And the Spanish version is http://www.thebitles.com/es/
which points back to the canonical version through this tag

```
<link rel="canonical" hreflang="en" href="/" />
```

I can't figure out where is the error, the return tags are there.
Anyone has an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my errors:
`<link rel="canonical" hreflang="en" href="/" />` does not exist, i had to replace it with
`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/" />` and that is a correct return tag.
Furtherly i missed the alternate/hreflang tags which point to the same page: `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="xx" href="yy" />`
which are required even if there are already the language meta tags `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="xx">`

Answer (score 1):

You should also use absolute URLS (the full paths)

like

```
href="http://www.example.com/us/"
```

instead of

```
"/us/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on searching for solutions to fix this problem myself, it looks like Google changed something and the Search Console now expects the `hreflang` tags to [be higher up on the page](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/hreflang-error-from-google-and-what-is-the-best-strategy-for-multisite/#post-818671).

Try moving the tags up in your `head` and see if that helps.

Comment: Done, waiting for updates in search console. But i've found out that the main errors were the ones in my own answer. Were your link tags correct or you made my same mistakes? P.S. I'm trying to give you +1 but i need 15 reputation :(